# How to insert data in SQL Server using F#?

Tags: f#

I want to make a module which helps to execute SQL query from F#. I unable to use System.Data.SqlClient and getting error.

```
module SQL_Helper

open System.Data.SqlClient

type SqlHelper (connection) =
    let exec bind parametres query = 
        use conn = new SqlConnection (connection)
        conn.Open()
        use cmd = new SqlCommand (query, conn)
        parametres |> List.iteri (fun i p -> 
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(sprintf "@p%d"  i, box p) |> ignore)
        bind cmd

    member __.Execute = exec <| fun c -> c.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore
    member __.Scalar  = exec <| fun c -> c.ExecuteScalar()
    member __.Read f  = exec <| fun c -> [ let read = c.ExecuteReader()
                                           while read.Read() do 
                                               yield f read ]
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? If you want to use a type provider you could try [SqlProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/).

Comment: @s952163   `use conn = new SqlConnection (connection)` SqlConnection is giving error **The type SqlConnection is not defined, maybe you want one of the following SqlClientPermiwsion**

Comment: I assume you've already got a package reference to the [System.Data.SqlClient NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/). Could you show us your .fsproj file so we can see how you referenced the package? I've seen cases where the package reference created by a tool was a conditional reference, and something had made the condition false.